# How to obtain a stacked area plot for a categorized data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just started exploring ggplot2, and I currently don't have an understanding of the aes objects it uses so frequently. I've tried several approaches to solving this problem, but it hasn't been working. Any help would be much appreciated!

So, I have a data frame that I've classified specifically for the purpose of plotting, which looks something like this:

```
> ggplotframe[1:8,]
  gamma weights assets
1 0.002    0.25      1
2 0.002    0.25      2
3 0.002    0.25      3
4 0.002    0.25      4
5 0.004    0.25      1
6 0.004    0.25      2
7 0.004    0.25      3
8 0.004    0.25      4
```

Now, I want to plot a stacked area chart, displaying the `weights` for each `asset`, as the `gamma` varies. Since there are 4 assets in this example, there are 4 different weights for each value of gamma, one for each asset, and they are tested over hundreds of such values.

Now, of the approaches I have tried, one is:

```
gg <- ggplot(ggplotframe, aes(x=gamma, y=weights))
gg <- gg + geom_area(aes(colour=assets, fill=assets))
gg
```

But in this case, the console flashes the error: `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try turning assets into a factor. Right now, it is trying to make one area, and thinks it needs to change the color and fill of that area by a continuous variable and ggplot doesn't support that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Axeman! But the answer quoted below works better for me since I am using the data frame for other sorting methods as well. :)

Comment: Yeah OK it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to turn the assets column into a factor explicity, you can do so within the ggplot call by placing `factor()` around `fill`  in the `geom_area`.

```
gg <- ggplot(ggplotframe, aes(x = gamma, y = weights))
gg <- gg + geom_area(aes(colour = factor(assets), fill = factor(assets)))
gg
```

Comment: You're welcome, remember to accept this as the answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: I have another question. For more than a specified number of assets, I get the following error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3493): colour, fill, x, y. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Be sure to add `factor(assets)` in colour as well.  This error is caused by an unequal subset of the data when trying to match the aesthetics.